# url, path in urlpatterns Django is not working

Tags: python, django

> path('',include('personal.urls')),
>
> ```
>  ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I run the server using `python manage.py runserver` for the following code I got this error.

**url patterns**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
#from django.conf.urls import url
#from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls)
    path('',include('personal.urls')),  
]
```

**url patterns for my app 'personal'**

```
from django.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

#import URLs
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),    
]
```

This is **views.py** code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'personal/home.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the comma after the first line. Replace with this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('personal.urls')),  
]
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be due to missing `namespace`. Try to include the `namespace` in your `main.urls`.

```
path('', include('personal.urls', namespace="personal")),
```

Comment: I tried with adding the missing comma and it worked. By the way what does "namespace" do?

Comment: `namespace` provide distinct identity to your `application`. It allows you uniquely reverse [named URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) even if different applications use the same URL names.